# EF 4 not loading foreign key object

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am running an ASP.NET MVC 3 application (C#).

I recently made a foreign key in my database nullable. This probably isn't best practice however it is necessary for my scenario. So now when I display my report (ASPX View Engine), the values for the object which I have made nullable in my db will not display.

The data structure now (simplified) is as follows:

```
Inventory
________________
InventoryID int PK
ShopID FK int NOT NULL
ProductID FK int NULL
```

The only change to this is that ProductID used to be Not Nullable.

My ActionResult is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InventoryReport(FormCollection formVariables, InventoryReportRequest reportRequest)
        {
            ModelContainer ctn = new ModelContainer();

            var query = ctn.Inventory.Where(ic => !ic.Deleted && ic.ShopID == reportRequest.ShopID);

            if (reportRequest.ProductID.HasValue)
            {
                query = (from ic in query
                         where reportRequest.ProductID == ic.ProductID
                         select ic);
            }

            List<Inventory> checks = query.ToList();

            if (checks.Count > 0)
            {
                return View(checks);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
```

When I debug though this Action, I can see that the ProductID is being retrieved, however the Product object remains null. So when I want to display my results in my view -

```
<table class="normal" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Shop
            </th>
            <th>
                **Product Name**
            </th>
            <th>
                **Product ID**
            </th>
            <th>
                Active
            </th>
        </tr>

    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateChecked) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Shop.Name) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                **<%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.Name) %>**
            </td>
            <td>
                **<%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.ProductID) %>**
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active) %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% } %> 

    </table>
```

The starred items appear blank.

Can any offer advice as to what I need to do to resolve this issue? If more information is required please just ask :)

Comment: Try this `var query = ctn.Inventory..Include("Shops").Where(ic => !ic.Deleted && ic.ShopID == reportRequest.ShopID);` which will add the appropriate changes the query to the db.

Comment: @saravanan thanks for the reply. I had tried that too with no result :S

Comment: as Gert Arnold pointed out, did you include the products in the context. did you happen to debug the code and get the values in the appropriate associations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it's more surprising that `Product` was loaded previously if you did not make any change to the query. For `Product` to be loaded you'd have to use `Include`, irrespective of the FK being nullable or not

```
ctn.Inventory.Include("Product").Where(...
```

Anyway, add the `Include` now and you'll be fine.

Comment: Hi Gert! Thanks for the reply. I have amended my query as above, however I am still not having any luck with it. I've never need to use 'Includes' previously which is strange, and despite not using 'Includes' for the Shop foreign key, all the Shop attributes still load.

Comment: Weird... I assume that `ModelContainer` is a context and `Inventory` nothing but a DbSet (or ObjectSet)?